# when do we use disable statement in verilog? is it possible to disable a block outside that block?

Tags: verilog

I want to disable a block by using an if condition outside that block. I am getting error:

```
UNEXPECTED DISABLE EXPECTING ASSERT
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: don't, especially if you want synthesisable Verilog.

Long answer: 'disable' is for tasks and named blocks, not modules. It has slightly suprising semantics: see http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00012.htm ; somewhat similar to 'break'. It's not very idiomatic verilog.

If you're trying to build a normal computational logic block that has an enable signal, wrap all your logic in `if (enabled) begin ... end`.

Comment: i tried giving that am getting an error GENERATE IF STATEMENT SHOULD BE A CONSTANT EXPRESSION. Actually my aim is to instantiate a module 54 times or 24 times depending on wether the a signal d=0 or 1.But am not able to do this using if else condition

Comment: Modules are always instantiated. Think real hardware: transistors don't go away when you're not using them. You have to instantiate the module but just leave it to do nothing if you don't need it. If your 0 or 1 is actually a constant you could make it a parameter. (It would help if you posted the verilog..)

Comment: i understand that the modules will be present in hardware even if i give if else condition.But there will be wastage of power if the module works when its output is not required rite?

Comment: Yes; although your synthesis tools may turn an enable into some clock gating to save power. If it's a very large block you can power gate it. Are you targeting ASIC or FPGA?

Comment: @twinkle, with the `if (enabled) begin ...` construction, the outputs won't switch when `enabled` is low, so this will substantially reduce the power consumption of the circuit (especially if the outputs go off-chip).

Comment: @pjc50 actually my aim is to design a configurable floating point multiplier which can perform 2 single precision operations or 1 double precision operation at a time. I have need to have a 2 dimensional array in which i have to arrange the partial products obtained for two single precision operation in case my signal d=0 or i have to store the partial product obtained for double precision in case d=1.am finding it difficult to code this in verilog.Can u suggest a method?

Comment: @photon am not able to instantiate modules inside if statement it is giving error GENERATE IF SHOULD BE A CONSTANAT EXPRESSION.I tried giving if under generate block that too is not working

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work. The if needs to be _inside_ an 'always' block. (This really isn't a good project to learn Verilog on!) How many clock cycles is the multiplier supposed to take?

Comment: @pjc50 there are 2 stages partial product generation stage and partial product addition stage.So it should happen in 2 clock cycles.

Comment: @pjc50 i started doing the project in verilog.am finding it difficult to write it efficiently can u suggest a method

Comment: @the photon i started doing the project in verilog.am finding it difficult to write it efficiently can u suggest a method

Comment: @twinkle, All I know about your project is that you tried to use `disable` and it didn't work. My main recommendation is to follow the style guides provided by your synthesis vendor. They will tell you the most efficient way to implement various functions, FSMs, etc.

Comment: @ the photon  actually my aim is to design a configurable floating point multiplier which can perform 2 single precision operations or 1 double precision operation at a time. I need to have a 2 dimensional array in which i have to arrange the partial products obtained for two single precision operation in case my signal d=0 or i have to store the partial product obtained for double precision in case d=1.am finding it difficult to code this in verilog.Can u suggest a method?

Comment: Repeating yourself really doesn't help.

Comment: Is it possible o implement this in verilog?

Comment: Anything is possible, but what you are trying to do does not make sense for idiomatic verilog.

Comment: @twinkle Part of your confusion may come from low power. If a set of transistors are not changing state, IE they are just sitting in a single state, then they are low powered. Driving an output actually is not what consumes power, unless the output has a resistive termination, which will not be the case in the FPGA. Instead charging and discharging teh capacitor is what makes up the power consumption.

Answer (score 2):

A common use for `disable` in your verilog testbench might be:

```
fork : wait_or_timeout
  begin : timeout
    #10_000; //#10ms
    $display("Timeout");
    $finish();
    disable wait_for_signal;
  end
  begin :wait_for_signal
    @(posedge SIGNAL);
    disable timeout;
  end
join
```

Here we start 2 parallel processes, the simulator will not execute any further code until both complete. Using disable, the first to complete disables the other.

For improved modularity and code reuse **Generate Statements** can be used. These are compile time constants though, they do not disable or powerdown hardware, they make hardware exist or not exist based on constant configuration options before running your sim or synthesis.

For power saving techniques, the use of enables in your flip-flops with auto-clock gating options for synthesis can result in good power savings.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
  if (~reset_n) begin
    //reset
  end
  else if (enabled) begin
    //<= nextvalue;
  end
  // no final else, if not enabled hold value
  //   this allows clk to be stopped
end
```